# contextPath cannot be resolved as a member of a request

Tags: jsp, weblogic, http-status-code-404, contextpath

I'm very new to JSP, and I tried [this](http://geronimo.apache.org/GMOxSAMPLES/5-minute-tutorial-on-enterprise-application-development-with-eclipse-and-geronimo.html) simple tutorial but in eclipse, in index.jsp i get warning "contextPath cannot be resolved as a member of request" and when I deploy and try to submit a form I get Error 404-not found.

I use Weblogic 12c and Eclipse Kepler

index.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/sayHello">
        <input type="text" name="name" /><input type="submit" value="Press me!" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just for your information, that 404 is completely unrelated to the warning. No need to focus on the warning.

Comment: well, thats always something, thanks :) so what may cause this? is there any way I can check where is the problem?

Comment: It just means there's nothing behind the URL `/sayHello`. Try requesting it manually by entering its URL in browser's address bar. You'll see that you still get a 404.